# how to change ip address with android on ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04

Say I get my internet through my phone to my pc via easytether app. Is there a way I can to change ip like a vpn server through my phone? My phone is android jelly bean 4.2.2 and pc is imac running ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

You can use on the of the VPN apps [Here](http://www.androidauthority.com/best-android-vpn-apps-577594/)

**VYPR VPN** is a really good one. If you use a lot of bandwidth you could also look into using [OpenVpn](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.blinkt.openvpn&hl=en) and [cryptostorm.is](http://cryptostorm.is) as the company is really well at matching your bandwidth.

*Note you can use OpenVpn with most any VPN service.*

This will pass all traffic off of your Android phone from your pc.